# How to execute some Clojure futures in a single thread?

Tags: multithreading, clojure, future

I'd like to create some futures in Clojure and run them all on a specific thread, to make sure they run one-at-a-time. Is this possible?

It's not hard to wrap the Java libraries to do this, but before I do that I want to make sure I'm not missing a Clojure way of doing it.  In Java I can do this by implementing `FutureTask` and submitting those tasks to a single-threaded executor.

Comment: Why would you want to create constructs which are designed for concurrency, only to enforce that they execute non-concurrently? Maybe you have existing tasks defined this way, or you normally execute them concurrently but want to enforce sequential execution for a limited time? Just curious.

Comment: Let's say there are multiple threads (eg, request threads in a server) all wanting to run tasks that use a shared resource X, which can be used by only one thread at a time. One solution is to grab a lock whenever accessing X. Another way is is to submit tasks (futures) to run on a single thread associated with X.  The other calling threads may or may not wait for the future's result.

Comment: Sure, but why create threads at all in this case? Why not just call the tasks as functions from a single thread?

Comment: I think the short answer is: because the system benefits from parallel execution in other areas. Like a web server with requests handled on separate threads. Then those threads need to do things that use resource X. This idea is not something I invented - it's a serial queue with async dispatch from Apple's GCD. Maybe the docs for that system will explain it better. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure's [future macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future) calls [future-call](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future-call) function which uses [a dedicated executor service](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6848). This means that you have no control to enforce a sequential execution.

On the other hand you can use [promise](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise) instead of `future` objects and one `future` thread to sequentially [deliver](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deliver) the results. Promise's API is similar to what `future`s provide. They have [deref](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref) and [realized?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/realized_q) too.

The following code example has the subtasks executed sequentially on a new thread in the background while the immediately returned result of the function contains the promises to the computed values.

```
(defn start-async-calc []
  (let [f1 (promise)
        f2 (promise)
        f3 (promise)]
    (future
      (deliver f1 (task-1))
      (deliver f2 (task-2))
      (deliver f3 (task-3)))
    {:task1 f1
     :task2 f2
     :task3 f3}))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to sequentialize the calls to `future` you can use it manually like this:

```
(do @(future 1)
    @(future 2)
    @(future 3))
```

they would still possibly called in different threads, but the next one won't be called until the previous has finished. This is guaranteed by the `@` (or `deref` function). This means that the thread in which you execute `do` form would be blocked with prev promise before it completes, and then spawn next one.

you can prettify it with macro like this:

```
(defmacro sequentialize [& futures]
  `(do ~@(map #(list `deref %) futures)))

user> (let [a (atom 1)]
        (sequentialize
         (future (swap! a #(* 10 %)))
         (future (swap! a #(+ 20 %)))
         (future (swap! a #(- %))))
        @a)
;;=> -30
```

this does exactly the same as manual `do`. Notice that mutations to `a` atom are in-order even if some threads run longer:

```
user> (let [a (atom 1)]
        (sequentialize
         (future (Thread/sleep 100)
                 (swap! a #(* 10 %)))
         (future (Thread/sleep 200)
                 (swap! a #(+ 20 %)))
         (future (swap! a #(- %))))
        @a)
;;=> -30
```

Answer (score 0):

[Manifold](https://github.com/ztellman/manifold) provides a way to create future [with specific executor](http://aleph.io/codox/manifold/manifold.deferred.html#var-future-with). It's not part of core Clojure lib, but it's still a high quality lib and probably a best option in case you need more flexibility dealing with futures than core lib provides (without resorting to Java interop).

Answer (score 0):

In addition the `promises` mentioned, you can use a `delay`. Promises have the problem that you can accidentally not deliver them, and create a deadlock scenario that's not possible with `future`s and `delay`s. The difference between a future and a delay is only the thread that the work is executed on. With a future, the work is done in the background, and with a delay the work is done by the first thread that tries to deref it. So if future's are a better fit than promises, you could always do something like:

```
(def result-1 (delay (long-calculation-1)))
(def result-2 (delay (long-calculation-2)))
(def result-3 (delay (long-calculation-3)))

(defn run-calcs []
  @(future
     @result-1
     @result-2
     @result-3))
```